# Python 3.8 on Windows 10/Linux (Manjaro 18.1.5): ModuleNotFoundError for TestPyPI package installed with pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, windows, pip

I followed along with the [package distribution tutorial](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/) for uploading a package on test.pypi.org from a Linux machine, and proceeded to try to install the package on a separate Windows machine.

On the Windows machine, I installed Python 3.8 and ticked the `Add Python 3.8 to PATH` box. No previous Python installation was present, and it installed to `C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\`.

In Environmental Variables, my `PATH` under "Users variables" is: `C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python38\Scripts\;C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python38\;%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps`.

My `PATH` under "System variables" is much longer, but it **contains no Python directories**.

I then [downloaded](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) and installed pip.

In Command Prompt, I first created a virtual environment with `py -m venv tutorial` and activated it with `Scripts\activate`. Activation was verified by the `(tutorial)` next to the prompt. Then, in the virtual env, with `py -m pip install ...` I installed my example package.

I can verify it's installed by seeing it in the output of `py -m pip list`:

```
Package                 Version
----------------------- -------
example-pkg-me          0.0.1
pip                     19.2.3
setuptools              41.2.0
```

`example-pkg-me` does not appear outside the virtual env.

The tutorial finishes by having you attempt an import in the Python interpreter:

```
py
>>> import example_pkg
```

but I get `` ModuleNotFoundError: No module named `example_pkg` ``. Why? Is something wrong with either of my `PATH`s? Note that the tutorial specifically mentions omitting the username (and `import example_pkg_me` issues the same error regardless).

Curiously, when trying to install and import a "mainstream (?)" package, it succeeds with no errors. I.e.,

`py -m pip install numpy`

and

```
py
>>> import numpy
```

works.

**Update:**
Same results on a separate Linux machine with the same steps where the only differences are that Python and pip were already present.

As an aside, if your package is intended to be run (as a GUI app) rather than imported in the interpreter as in the tutorial, how would the person who installed it run it? Would they have to navigate to the directory where the package files were physically installed and run a main.py script there? Is there a better way (like freezing the package as an executable with the likes of cx_Freeze and distributing the EXE instead of relying on pip installations)? Or maybe just expect them to download a repository, run `py setup.py install`, and then a main.py script?

Comment: The "downloaded and installed pip" step is unnecessary. pip is installed by default, unless you disabled the option to install it. Also, since you have the "Scripts" directory in `PATH`, you can just run `pip`, `pip3`, or `pip3.8` instead of `py -m pip`, `py -3 -m pip`, or `py -3.8 -m pip`. The only time you need `py -m pip` is when upgrading pip itself.

Comment: That tutorial has you install the package into a virtual environment. Did you maybe follow those instructions with an active virtual environment? Interactive `py` and `py -m` will use an active virtual environment.

Comment: I did indeed use a virtual env. I'll update my question.